# Best practice: Is it better to receive data via doPost(e) or google.script.run.someFunction(data)?

Tags: post, google-apps-script

I'm making an application that can pass form from a web page to a Google spreadsheet. I've found a two basic ways how to do that:

1) I submit a form on a web page and then I process an event via `doPost(e) -> JSON.stringify(e)`. (This is in "code.gs".)

or

2) I make a function i.e. "writeToCellA1()" and call it as follows `google.script.run.writeToCellA1(someData)`. (This is in "index.html")

The question is: Is there some background of those two possible ways of writing data to Google spradsheet that suggests that one of them is superior? Safer, more raliable, more promising future functions developement etc....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `doPost`, you have to determine what actual function to call by inspecting the payload, since all input from the client is going to this single entry point. All function parameters have to be object-based (i.e. named). Unless you use asynchronous methods to connect, you will block your client code. Further, any response you receive will be either `ContentService` or `HtmlService`.

If you use the `google.script.run` pattern, your calls can be directed to a specific server function, you can easily specify function parameters in traditional manners (i.e. both positional and object-based), your calls are guaranteed to be asynchronous, and you can return most serializable data types directly.

There is additionally an access argument - `doPost` is available to any sufficiently authorized client, perhaps even anonymous, per the settings of your published web app. This could be external code that you or others write, e.g. a php script. Calls made via `google.script.run` are only available from a page served by `HtmlService` (you can use the Apps Script API to target individual functions from external code). Note that you are not required to publish as a webapp to use `google.script.run` - i.e. you can use these in sidebars and modal dialogs, too.

There is also the manner of error / response handling. If you want to add success and failure callbacks for these calls to `doPost`, you will need to do more work than if you want to do the same for calls with `google.script.run` - the latter supports easily adding these with two methods, `withSuccessHandler` and `withFailureHandler`.

Regardless, you should review the official documentation for these topics:

- [doPost](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#dogete_and_doposte)
- [web apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Client-server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. Unfortunately I can not vote it up yet, but I "accepted" it. Thank you very much!